# Do non standard domain extensions affect TTL (BIND SERVER)

Tags: domain-name-system, bind

I have researched this it seems to no end and I cannot find a definitive answer.

We have over 500 domains with GoDaddy, and we point them to an internal DNS server that we use Bind to manage.

The strange thing is, that whenever we point a **standard** domain IE `.com` `.net`, `.org`, `.us`, `.info` etc etc etc the TTL is super fast almost all of the time with a few outliers.  However when we do some of the *new* **non-standard** urls the TTL isn't only dodgy, it's non existent in some areas of the US.  I know that GoDaddy points correctly, because I can `dig` from, say, Seattle and hit my DNS server correctly -- Then at the same time `dig` from Chicago and propagation just doesn't happen.  I even try updating serials to try to reset caching to no avail.

It is only these non-standard URLs that we're having issues with.  Is this just some cosmic coincidence or is there a reason behind this?  Just for clarity in this OP, I will post the configuration of one of the domains that won't propagate "correctly" or "completely".  --  Please tell me that there is something with Bind that I can configure or change to get these to propagate correctly, and that it's not just that the interwebs aren't ready for non-standard domains!

**named.conf.local**

```
zone "somesite.builders" {
     type master;
     file "/var/lib/bind/somesite.builders.hosts";
     };
```

**somsite.builders.hosts**

```
$ttl 38400
somesite.builders.                       IN          SOA      ns1.somedns.com. email.email.com. (
                            1502145907
                            10800
                            3600
                            604800
                            38400 )
somesite.builders.                       IN       NS      ns1.somedns.com.
somesite.builders.                       IN       A       xx.xx.xx.xx
www.somesite.builders.                   IN       A       40.xx.xx.xx
mail.somesite.builders.                  IN       A       173.xx.xx.xx
webmail.somesite.builders.               IN       A       173.xx.xx.xx
somesite.builders.                       IN       MX      10 mx1.somemail.com.
somesite.builders.                       IN       MX      20 mx2.somemail.com.
```

**Whats My DNS results after 4 days (96 hours)**

[image: Incomplete Propagation]

Answer (score 2):

It's really not the case that the TLDs you speak of are *non-standard*, rather they are just relatively newly established.

Geographical location is not an actual factor that matters. The recursive nameserver in use (typically provided by the ISP) and its connectivity is what matters in this regard.

The use of the term "propagation" in relation caching behavior and TTLs is misleading, it makes it sound like some data is being actively spread (possibly even in some kind of linear fashion, which would tie in with the idea that geography would matter) while in reality it's a matter of waiting for any already cached old data to expire (which happens independently on each caching server).

As for the problem at hand, there's really not enough information in the question to say anything definite about what the problem is.
That said, to me it doesn't appear particularly likely that caching is the issue if you have already waited four days. It seems more likely that there is some form of misconfiguration that causes the continued generation of new bad answers.

My suggestion would be to actually have a close look at both what the actual answers from recursive nameservers that do not answer as desired are as well as how all of the TLD nameservers respond as well as how all of the nameservers for your own zone respond.

Do these recursive servers say that your domain does not exist, if so does the `SOA` at least match the actual TLD zone? If it doesn't match, that could be a sign that the recursive server may have some bad configuration that interferes.

As for the authoritative side, for this purpose `dig +trace +add example.com NS` and `dig +nssearch example.com` style commands may serve as a starting point and then work your way through from there. Services such as [DNSViz](http://dnsviz.net/) may also be helpful to get a better overview.

If there are any inconsistencies, that could also explain the problem.

Just as an example where the choice of TLD would end up being a factor even though conceptually there is no difference, if one of the TLD zone's N nameservers for whatever reason does not get updated with the current version of their zone and still claims that your domain name does not exist (a valid response, does not trigger any retries) while their other nameservers correctly respond with a referral to your nameservers, there would be a 1/N chance that any given recursive nameserver will know for a fact, from a trusted source, that your domain name is non-existent and act as such.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing technically different between the TLDs; caching and zone transfers works the same way for them all. BTW, you seem to have some confusion between these two:

- TTL affects only caching i.e. how long *recursive* servers keeps the *record* (not entire zone).
- SOA serial affects only zone transfers; does the master have newer zone than the other *authoritative* servers. In addition, master may send notifications when the zone changes.

Comment: It should be noted that all domains are purchased through us, and that this is during initial setup..  So what you are saying, all things being equal, that this is just a coincidence?  I have added an image to the OP denoting the "incompleteness" of the transfer.

Answer (score 1):

Contrary to @Esa Jokinen, I posit that there is a difference between TLDs: the nameservers for the TLD itself.  If the TLD itself is unresolvable because its nameservers are flakey, then your name will not be resolvable either.

I suppose there might also be DNS servers and/or firewalls that limit the acceptable TLDs; that would be contrary to the specifications but it wouldn't surprise me.

Comment: No need to suppose, this (software rejecting new TLDs, or even TLDs with more than 4 characters) is a real and big problem. See for example: https://uasg.tech/ which has a lot of information about the "Universal Acceptance" issue and mitigations.

Comment: Yeah, my answer was too optimistic.